# How can I use index or rindex with a block in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, enumerable

Is there any Array or Enumerable built-in that allows me to search for an element using a block, and return its index?

Something along the lines of :

```
ar = [15,2,33,4,50,69]
indexes = ar.find_indexes {|item| item > 4 == 0}
# indexes will now contain 0,2,4,5
```

It would be very easy to add my own, but I'd like to know if this already exists?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there's anything built-in, at least I didn't notice anything previously undetected in the [Array](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html) or [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html) docs.

This is pretty terse, though:

```
(0..ar.size-1).select { |i| ar[i] > 4 }
```

EDIT: Should have mentioned this is Ruby 1.8.6.

ANOTHER EDIT: forgot triple-dot, which saves a whole character, as well as cleaning up the `-1`, which I wasn't comfortable with:

```
(0...ar.size).select { |i| ar[i] > 4 }
```

Answer (score 3):

I understand this is only ruby 1.9

```
indexes = ar.collect.with_index { |elem, index| index if elem > 4 }.
             select { |elem| not elem.nil? }
```

EDIT: for ruby 1.8 try

```
require 'enumerator'
indexes = ar.to_enum(:each_with_index).
             collect { |elem, index| index if elem > 4 }.
             select { |elem| not elem.nil? }
```

Comment: `xs.select { |elem| not elem.nil? }` -> `xs.compact`

Answer (score 1):

Just let explode the power of inject method!!! ;-)

```
ar.inject([]){|a,i| a.empty? ? a << [0, i] : a << [a.last[0]+1,i]}
  .select{|a| a[1] > 4}
  .map{|a| a[0]}
```

(works with ruby 1.8.6)

Comment: This one should be a pleasure to debug.

Comment: Sure, but luckily there is no need for debugging ;)

Comment: It never is. Until there is :)

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can always monkey patch it if you want:

```
class Array
  def find_indexes(&block)
    (0..size-1).select { |i| block.call(self[i]) }
  end
end

ar = [15,2,33,4,50,69]
p ar.find_indexes {|item| item > 4 }  #=> [0, 2, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Yeah, I know this is an option, but I thought maybe something equivalent already existed.

Answer (score 0):

It's essentially Mike Woodhouse's answer reformatted to remove the ugly range.

```
ar.each_index.select{|item| item > 4}
```

Here's a version of johnanthonyboyd's answer that works with Ruby 1.8.7

```
ar.enum_with_index.each.select{|item| item.first > 4}.map(&:last)
```

Comment: Can't see how the [each_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002174) thing works - it would have to return an Enumerable, wouldn't it?

enum_with_index looks useful, but should note it's 1.8.7 and above only, as is the handy map(&:...) thing (outside Rails). Also, the docs suggest it needs `require enumerator`. I'm still on 1.8.6, so I can't check.

Comment: Each and each_index and other iterator methods return the Enumerable object it iterated through. As for the syntax of the other, it worked in my local irb install (using ruby 1.8.7, I didn't realize it was a recent addition)

Comment: I guess you meant: `ar.each_index.select { |idx| ar[idx] > 4}`